# GLSL shader issue

Tags: opengl, glsl

I created two shaders for my program to render simple objects.

Vertex shader source:

```
#version 400 core
layout (location = 1) in vec4 i_vertexCoords;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 i_textureCoords;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 i_normalCoords;
layout (location = 4) in int i_material;

uniform mat4 u_transform;

out VertexData {
    vec3 textureCoords;
    vec3 normalCoords;
    int material;
} vs_out;

void main() {
    vs_out.textureCoords = i_textureCoords;
    vs_out.material = i_material;
    gl_Position = u_transform * i_vertexCoords;
    vs_out.normalCoords = gl_Position.xyz;
}
```

Fragment shader source:

```
#version 400 core
struct MaterialStruct {
    int ambientTexutre;
    int diffuseTexture;
    int specularTexture;
    int bumpTexture;

    vec4 ambientColor;
    vec4 diffuseColor;
    vec4 specularColor;

    float specularComponent;
    float alpha;
    int illuminationModel;
};

in VertexData {
    vec3 textureCoords;
    vec3 normalCoords;
    int material;
} vs_out;

layout (std140) uniform MaterialsBlock {
    MaterialStruct materials[8];
} u_materials;

uniform sampler2D u_samplers[16];

out vec4 fs_color;


void main() {
    MaterialStruct m = u_materials.materials[vs_out.material];
    fs_color = vec4(m.diffuseColor.rgb, m.diffuseColor.a * m.alpha);
}
```

Program created with this two shaders renders picture 2
 [image: axes]
When I change `main()` function contents to next:

```
void main() {
    MaterialStruct m = u_materials.materials[vs_out.material];
    fs_color = vec4(m.diffuseColor.rgb * (vs_out.normalCoords.z + 0.5), m.diffuseColor.a * m.alpha);
}
```

It renders picture 1, but materials still exists (if I'm trying to select material from `u_materials.materials` manually it works). Shader thinks what `vs_out.material` is constant and equals 0, but it isn't. Data is not changed (excluding transformation matrix)
Could someone explain the solution of this problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment `Shader thinks what vs_out.material is constant and equals 0, but it isn't`.  The only change in the fragment shader appears to be the use of `(vs_out.normalCoords.z + 0.5)` as a multiplier in the colour calculation.  Given that the colour appears to be bleached out in figure 1 is it possible that `vs_out.normalCoords.z` has some large value?

Comment: Not sure what you expect from multiplying a color with a normal component + 0.5. Also, not sure of this on the vertex shader: `vs_out.normalCoords = gl_Position.xyz;`. That's certainly not a normal to the vertex.

Comment: vs_out.normalCoords is just a gl_Position of vertex in this shader pair. vs_out.normalCoords.z fits range [0.1 .. 0.9]. When I change `vs_out.material` in `MaterialStruct m = u_materials.materials[vs_out.material]` to explicit value (0, 1 or 2) full model changes color correspondingly to gray, red and white. The problem of shader is substitution of `vs_out.material` to `0` when compiling shaders.

Comment: Your shaders shouldn't even compile, since your `int` varying isn't declared as `flat`.

Comment: @derhass , I'm very thankful to you. I added flat qualifier to `vs_out.material` variable and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GLSL 4.5 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) states in section 4.3.4 "Input Variables":

> Fragment shader inputs that are signed or unsigned integers, integer vectors, or any double-precision
>   floating-point type must be qualified with the interpolation qualifier `flat`.

You can't use interpolation with those types, and actually, your code shouldn't compile on a strict implementation.